# EPR spectrum of a singlet-triplet mixture

Tags: spectroscopy

Through EPR measurements it is possible to gain information about the spin states of molecules. So a singlet state will give no signal/only noise and a molecule with unpaired electrons will result in an EPR spectrum.

What happens if a measured sample would contain a mixture of singlet and triplet state molecules (of the same species)? Will there be a signal for the triplet state or is there any interaction between both that hinders the experimentalist from measuring the triplet states?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem AFAIK.